# MYSQL bitwise AND

Tags: mysql

```
LanguageTable
language_ID | language
1           | english
2           | german
3           | french

EmployeeTable
employee_ID | language_ID
1           | 1
2           | 2
2           | 3
3           | 3
4           | 2
```

Select the employee who speaks German and French

And don't tell me

SELECT EmployeeTable.employee_ID
FROM EmployeeTable
WHERE language_ID = 3 & 2

because that doesn't work

Comment: use where in() of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.employee_ID  from EmployeeTable a join EmployeeTable b on a.employee_ID =b.employee_ID  where a.language_ID='2' and b.language_ID='3'
```

try this